# In terms of remediation, what is sequestration?

Tags: adsorption

I am reading about use of zero valent iron in remediation of heavy metals.
Is sequestration just a broader term for sorption?

Answer (score 1):

Sequestration is any way of preventing the heavy metals from being able to harmfully react with biologically important molecules. In the case of zero-valent iron nanoparticles, the heavy metals are sequestered by sorption as well as reduction. However, there are other methods of sequestration, such as chelation.